# How to call one xib file from another class,ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, xib

I have googled a lot, but some where I am doing a mistake regarding the *xib* file. I have four buttons in view controller.xib file. Then when I tap the button one two three, alertinputtypetext has to be dislayed. Its done successfully.

But when i tap the fourth button, I need to display pickerView.xib. But when I am debugging the application, the application sequence is missing and showing the main.m class.

Please help me somebody. Give me hint to proceed further.

Comment: you want to display a new view in a new controller, or want to load the view in the same view controller?

Comment: Please show the code that runs when the fourth button is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I need to display the another file pickerView.xib" ?.. if pickerView is UIViewController subclass you could show it simply .. if its just a nib file contains a pickerView , you could use `loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options` , but actually you don't need to put it in separate nib file .. `xib` can hold more than one view inside it , so you could use you original `viewController.xib` , or what I prefer is to it programmatically without loading it from xib.